# tar a directory and only include certain file types

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, tar

Following the instructions here: http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/20_08.html

I'm aiming to tar up a directory but only want to include .php files from that directory.

Given the aforementioned instructions, I've come up with this command. It creates a file called IncludeTheseFiles which lists all the .php files, then the tar is supposed to do it's job only using the files listed in IncludeTheseFiles

```
find myProjectDirectory -type f -print | \
egrep '(\.[php]|[Mm]akefile)$' > IncludeTheseFiles
tar cvf myProjectTarName -I IncludeTheseFiles
```

However, when I run this it doesn't like the I include option?

```
tar: invalid option -- I
```

Comment: Note that I realize in this context it seems a little overkill creating the list of files when I could just do something like:

tar cvf myProjectTarName.tar `find myProjectDirectory -name '*.php'`

But my end goal is actually to tar up more than just .php files (ex: all php, html, inc, css, js files), which is why I am doing it the above way.

Comment: On my system with GNU `tar` version 1.22, the `-I` option is used to specify a compression program.

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick, no comparison file needed:

```
find myProjectDirectory -type f \( -name \*\.php -o -name \*\.js -o -name \*\.css -o -name \*\.inc \) | xargs tar -rf myProjectTarName.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the man page for Gnu tar on my Ubuntu 8.04 system, it says:

```
-T, --files-from F
    get names to extract or archive from file F
```

It does not reference a `-I` option other than to mention that historically it was used to request bzip compression.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify stdin as the source for your filenames. Try:

```
find myProjectDirectory -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(.*\.[php]|[Mm]akefile)$ -print | \
tar cvf myProjectTarName --files-from=-
```